# Repetir n veces una funcion

Tags: python, lista, pandas, bucle-for

soy realmente nuevo en Python y vaya que me ha pillado por sorpresa, tengo la siguiente situación:

```
    def nombres(nombre,edad):
        print(f"nombre - edad")
        print(f"{nombre} - {edad}")

    lista_de_integrantes =  ['Diego', 19],["Alan", 20],["Paola",27]

    for nombre,edad in lista_de_integrantes:
        nombres(nombre,edad)
```

El resultado que arrojara me gustaría que fuera el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo a mi me sale esto alguien que me pueda ayudar o orientar para poder hacerlo lo agradecería mucho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como nota, debo usar el for para recorrer mi lista de datos.

como dato adicional al final yo voy a tener n personas en mi lista y con ello realizar un DataFrame e hice esto:

```
import pandas as pd

def nombres(nombre,edad):
    #print(f"{nombre} - {edad}")
    df = pd.DataFrame([nombre],[edad])
    print(df)
    df.to_excel('PruebaDF.xlsx')


    lista_de_integrantes =  ['Diego', 19],["Alan", 20],["Paola",27]

    for nombre,edad in lista_de_integrantes:
       nombres(nombre,edad)
```

y lo que me da resultado en mi excel es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme o si es necesario cambiar mi función o que podría solucionar este tema

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Repetir n veces una función con lista como argumentos PYTHON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514065/repetir-n-veces-una-funci%c3%b3n-con-lista-como-argumentos-python)

Answer (score 0):

solo debes sacar el primer print de la funcion ya que se ejecuta cada vez que se llama la funcion.

ejemplo:

```
def nombres(nombre,edad):
   print(f"{nombre} - {edad}")


lista_de_integrantes =  ['Diego', 19],["Alan", 20],["Paola",27]
print(f"nombre - edad")

for nombre,edad in lista_de_integrantes:
   nombres(nombre,edad)
```

Comment: al final yo busco crear un dataFrame e hize lo siguiente:
import pandas as pd

def nombres(nombre,edad):
   #print(f"{nombre} - {edad}")
   df = pd.DataFrame([nombre],[edad])
   print(df)


lista_de_integrantes =  ['Diego', 19],["Alan", 20],["Paola",27]

for nombre,edad in lista_de_integrantes:
   nombres(nombre,edad)