# Repetir n veces una función con lista como argumentos PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, pandas, bucle-for, dataframe

tengo el siguiente problemas el cual tratare de plantear para que puedan ayudarme.

mi programa inicial es el siguiente.

```
nombre = input('Digite su nombre ')
edad = input('Digite su edad ')
sexo = input('Digite su Sexo M-Mujer, H-Hombre ')

def result(nombre,edad,sexo):
    if sexo == 'H':
        print(f"Su nombre es: {nombre} , su edad es {edad} y su sexo es Masculino")
    else:
        print(f"Su nombre es: {nombre} , su edad es {edad} y su sexo es Femenino")

result(nombre,edad,sexo)
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, ahora si yo quisiera pasar mis argumentos o parámetros, mediante una lista, como lo siguiente:

```
def result(nombre,edad,sexo):
    if sexo == 'H':
        print(f"Su nombre es: {nombre} , su edad es {edad} y su sexo es Masculino")
    else:
        print(f"Su nombre es: {nombre} , su edad es {edad} y su sexo es Femenino")

lista_personas =  ['Diego', 19,'H'],["Alan", 20,'H'],["Paola",27,'M']

for nombre, edad, sexo in lista_personas:
    result(nombre,edad,sexo)
```

Me da el resultado en pantalla correctamente pero si esto yo lo quiero llevar a un DataFrame no me deja hacerlo correctamente, por lo que entiendo mi función se repite n veces mientras haya datos:

```
import pandas as pd

def result(nombre,edad,sexo):
    resultado = []
    if sexo == 'H':
        sx = 'Masculino'
    else:
        sx = 'Femenino'
    resultado.append([nombre,edad,sexo],)
    df = pd.DataFrame(resultado)
    print(df)


lista_personas =  ['Diego', 19,'H'],["Alan", 20,'H'],["Paola",27,'M']

for nombre, edad, sexo in lista_personas:
    result(nombre,edad,sexo)
```

Me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que es por que la función se repite n veces y crea n DataFrame, por lo que necesito buscar la manera para que solo genere un DataFrame y los valores estén contenidos, como adicional siempre obtendré datos o parámetros de mi lista que estos también serán n datos, espero puedan ayudarme para obtener algo final así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Otra persona de tu misma clase o colegio ha hecho la misma pregunta, puse el link en el comentario anterior, tienen hasta el mismo ejemplo de Dataframe.

Comment: Pero no nos respondieron como queríamos :(

Comment: Jajajajajajajaja. Con abrir N preguntas con lo mismo no van a hacer que respondan más rápido; al contrario, dividen la atención de la gente. Y pues, que el dueño de la pregunta le diga a quien responde por qué no sirve la respuesta. Jajajaja

Comment: Hahaha, antes de hacer una pregunta es importante buscar si ya se ha hecho antes, de otra forma corres riesgo de que tu pregunta sea cerrada o votada negativamente. Voy a revisar la información que tu agregaste que no está en la otra pregunta y ver si puedo ayudar.

Comment: Seria d emucha ayuda gracias ,sorry

Comment: Es necesario que a tu función ingreses "nombre", "edad" y "sexo"? Es posible que ingreses únicamente un parámetro "lista_personas" y adentro de tu función recorrer la lista?

Comment: De hecho yo solo necesito los parámetros por lista. entonces sería recorres la lista

Comment: Es decir, si al final obtienes un dataframe único con las columnas que especificaste ya es suficiente? O necesitas forzosamente crear una función para recorrer la lista?

Comment: Si, necesito crear una función para recorrer la lista. Es decir el objetivo es entender como hacer que se repita mi función n veces pero al final poder agrupar el resultado en un DataFrame e imprima en pantalla. Es decir entiendo que mi función se repite las n veces. yo necesito que se repita una sola vez para n datos y así obtener el resultado. no se si me explico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías crear un dataframe vacío `df2` y un dataframe adentro de tu función `df` y luego retornarlo para ser concatenado al `df2`

```
import pandas as pd

def result(nombre,edad,sexo):
  resultado = []
  if sexo == 'H':
    sx = 'Masculino'
  else:
    sx = 'Femenino'
  resultado.append([nombre,edad,sexo])
  
  #Esto crea un dataframe con la información de cada persona
  df = pd.DataFrame(resultado, columns = ['Nombre', 'Edad', 'Sexo'])
  
  #Esto regresa el dataframe para ser utilizado fuera de la función
  return df
  


lista_personas =  ['Diego', 19,'H'],["Alan", 20,'H'],["Paola",27,'M']

#Esto crea un dataframe vacío pero con las columnas que necesitas
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Nombre', 'Edad', 'Sexo'])

for nombre, edad, sexo in lista_personas:
  #Esto concatena el dataframe que devuelve tu función en el dataframe vacío, cada ciclo agrega una fila más
  df2 = df2.append(result(nombre,edad,sexo), ignore_index=True)

print(df2)
```